# How do I find missing number from even number {2,4,6,8,10,14}

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find missing number from even number

**eg**: *{2,4,6,8,10,14};*  // output should be 12

I tried:

```
public class MissingNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = {2,4,6,8,10,14};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + a[i];
    } 


    int sum1 = 0;
    for(int j=1; j<=7; j++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + j;
    } 
    System.out.println("missing number is:"+(sum1-sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: As none of the answer point it out. Your `sum1` is were your approach goes wrong as the increments are: [+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7] which has nothing to do with even numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding `j*2` to `sum1`? Or otherwise multiplying `sum1` by 2 to get the sum of the even numbers

Answer (score 3):

You can use the idea that `a[i+1]` must equal `a[i]+2` for your number stream to be considered valid. If `a[i]+2 != a[i+1]` then `a[i]+2` is the number which is missing from your stream of even numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] a = {2,4,6,8,10,14};            // create Array
  Arrays.sort(a);                       // Sort Array (Just in case)
  int missing = -1;                     // Default value if no missing int is found
  for (int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++) {  // loop through Array
    if(a[i]+2 != a[i+1]) {              // check if expected next number exists
      missing = a[i]+2;                 // sets missing to the missing number
      break;                            // stops the for loop
    }
  }
  System.out.println("missing number is: " + missing);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are looking at sums unless you are sure your series of numbers always only is missing one number.

Otherwise, how about something like this:

```
    int a[] = {2,4,6,8,10,14};

    int expected = 2;
    for (int val : a) {
        if (expected != val) {
            System.out.println("Missing number is " + expected);
        }
        expected = expected +2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the even sum an check with the array element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14};

    int sum = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != sum) {
            System.out.println("missing number is: " + sum);
            break;
        }
        sum = sum + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in your code. By these changes, you will get your answer.

```
public class MissingNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = {2,4,6,8,10,14};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        } 

        int sum1 = 0;
        int even = 2;
        for (int j=0; j<=a.length; j++) {
            sum1 = sum1 + even;
            even = even + 2;
        }

        System.out.println("missing number is:"+(sum1-sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions above, but all of them have O(N) complexity. 
I believe that you can solve this problem with O(log N) using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm.

Raw code:

```
public class MissingNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {2,4,8,10, 12, 14};
        int start = 0;
        int end = a.length;
        int pointer = 0;
        while (end - start > 1) {
            if (a[pointer] == (pointer + 1) * 2) {
                start = pointer;
            } else {
                end = pointer;
            }
            pointer = (start + end) / 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Missing element: " + (pointer + 2) * 2);
    }
}
```

You can add some more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```java
// create the set of initial values to use them in filter step.
Set<Integer> givenValues = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

OptionalInt first =
    // generate range by 2 and limit it to size of input array
    IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 2).limit(a.length)
    // filter out only this value that are not in givenValues
    .filter(i -> !givenValues.contains(i))
    // get first value
        .findFirst();

// finally it have to be check if found any value. If not then return default value.
System.out.println("missing number is: "+first.orElse(-1));
```

It can be too over engineering. But it does not depend on order of given input.

Answer (score 0):

// Missing Number Fast

```
public int missingIntegerFast(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
        sum += i;
    }
    int n = arr.length + 1;
    return (n * (n - 1) / 2) - sum;
}
```